# multicheckboxes zend form multi populate

Tags: zend-framework, forms, checkbox

I want to populate the form with multicheckboxes and the multicheckboxes are grouped together, so if I have a multi check box checked, I will view them all. The normal populate is not working. It just gets me one of the checkboxes. This is my code.

```
public function addEditAction() {


    $id = (int) $this->_request->getParam('id');

    $request = $this->getRequest();

    $form = new Admin_Form_Tab();

    $db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();

    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        if ($form->isValid($request->getPost())) {
            if (isset($id) && $id != "") {
                $gettag = $form->getValue('tag_id');
                $gettags = count($gettag);
                try {
                    //shift the orders to
                    $select = $db->select()->from(array('t' => 'tab'), array('t.id',
                                't.title',
                                't.tab_position',
                                't.order',
                                't.is_active',
                                't.is_deleted'))->where('id = ?', $id);
                    $currentTab = $db->fetchRow($select);
                    $var3 = array('tab.order' => new Zend_Db_Expr('tab.order - 1'));
                    $var4 = array('tab.order >= ' . $currentTab['order'], 'is_active=1', 'is_deleted=0', 'tab_position=1');
                    $db->update('tab', $var3, $var4);
                    $var = array('tab.order' => new Zend_Db_Expr('tab.order + 1'));
                    $var2 = array('tab.order >= ' . $form->getValue('order'), 'is_active=1', 'is_deleted=0', 'tab_position=1');
                    $db->update('tab', $var, $var2);
                    $db->delete('tab_tag', array('tab_id = ?' => $id));
                    foreach ($gettag as $value) {

                        $db->insert('tab_tag',
                                array(
                                    'tag_id' => $value,
                                    'tab_id' => $id
                        ));
                    }
                    $db->update('tab', array(
                        'title' => $form->getValue('title'),
                        'body' => $form->getValue('body'),
                        'is_active' => $form->getValue('is_active'),
                        'banner_link' => $form->getValue('banner_link'),
                        'tab_path' => $form->getValue('tab_path'),
                        'link_open' => $form->getValue('link_open'),
                        'tab_position' => $form->getValue('tab_position'),
                        'tab_parent' => $form->getValue('tab_parent')
                            ),
                            array('id =?' => $id));
                    $this->flash('Tab Updated', 'admin/tab');
                } catch (Exception $e) {

                    $this->flash($e->getMessage(), 'admin/tab');
                }
            } else {
                try {
                    $formValues = $form->getValues();
                    $formValues['created_by'] = 1;
                    $formValues['created_date'] = date('Y/m/d H:i:s');
                    $formValues['is_deleted'] = 0;

                    $var = array('tab.order' => new Zend_Db_Expr('tab.order + 1'));
                    $var2 = array('tab.order >= ' . $form->getValue('order'), 'is_active=1', 'is_deleted=0', 'tab_position=1');
                    $db->update('tab', $var, $var2);

                    foreach ($gettag as $value) {

                        $db->insert('tab_tag',
                                array(
                                    'tag_id' => $value,
                                    'tab_id' => $id
                        ));
                    }
                    $db->insert('tab', array(
                        'title' => $form->getValue('title'),
                        'body' => $form->getValue('body'),
                        'is_active' => $form->getValue('is_active'),
                        'banner_link' => $form->getValue('banner_link'),
                        'tab_path' => $form->getValue('tab_path'),
                        'link_open' => $form->getValue('link_open'),
                        'tab_position' => $form->getValue('tab_position'),
                        'tab_parent' => $form->getValue('tab_parent')
                    ));




                    $this->flash('Tab inserted', 'admin/tab');
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    $this->flash($e->getMessage(), 'admin/tab');
                }
            }
        }
    }
    /*
     * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
     * and open the template in the editor.
     */


    if (isset($id) && $id != "") {
        $values = $db->fetchRow($db->select()
                ->from(array('t'=>'tab'))
                ->joinLeft(array('tt'=>'tab_tag'), 'tt.tab_id = t.id'));
        $form->populate($values);
    }

    $this->view->form = $form;
}
```

Comment: Re-asking the same question isn't acceptable behavior here.  If you want to draw attention to your question, you will be allowed to [place a bounty on it](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty) after two days.  You can also [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5869027/edit) to add additional information, which may make your question easier to understand and answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To populate multicheckbox you have to provide array with the key of checkboxes that has to be checked:

```
$values = array(
    'my_mylticheckbox' => array(1,3,5)
);
$form->populate($values);
```

or if you want to make checked only one checkbox:

```
$values = array('my_multicheckbox' => 3);
$form->populate($values);
```

So, just make sure you pass an array as the value for you multicheckbox.

Comment: i tried what you said i put the checkboxes value in an array and still facing the same problem only one checkbox is working this is what i did :$values = array($form->getValue('tag_id'));

        if (isset($id) && $id != "") {
            $values = $db->fetchRow($db->select()
                    ->from(array('t'=>'tab'))
                    ->joinLeft(array('tt'=>'tab_tag'), 'tt.tab_id = t.id'));
            $form->populate($values);
        }

Comment: Not correct. Should be $values = $db->fetchRow(...); $values['my_multicheckboxes'] = array(...all values for checkboxes...); If your checkboxes are from tab_tag table then I think you should not do this in one query. First query select data for tab, and second should select tab_tags to produce flat array for multicheckbox.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are doing a `$form>populate()` on the form before you add all the elements to the `cat_parent` control. Reversing the order of those two blocks - first add the cats to the `cat_parent` control, then add the get the db values and populate - should do the trick.

[As a side comment, I'd probably push much of this down into the form itself. Allow your form to take the `noChildsCategory` object/array in the constructor, then let the `init()` value add the `multiOptions`. Also, I'd probably push the db read/write into a model object of some sort. Then the controller becomes much slimmer and you can unit test the forms and models independent of the controller code. Just a thought.]

Answer (score 0):

```
$values = $this->getEntityManager()      
               ->getRepository('Application\Entity\Tab')          
               ->findBy(array(              
                   "id" => $id
                 ));

$arrayIds = array();
foreach ($values as $value) {
    $arrayIds[] = $value->getId();            
}  
$form->get('your_check_name')->setValue($arrayIds);
```

1) Fetch all ids and direct set into checkbox form field.so it will automatically populate.